# default_random_engine isn't randomizing values for me

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

When I run my function my `x` and `y` values stay the same every time it is run.  I'm not sure if I am using the default_random_engine incorrectly or not.  How can I get my `x` and `y` values using the `dist(engine)` to randomize and not be the same output every time the program executes?

Comment: Forget about `default_random_engine`, its inclusion in the standard was a mistake. Use `mt19937` or `mt19937_64` instead.

Comment: Show some code. Without it it's not possible to say whether you're "using the default_random_engine incorrectly or not".

Answer (score 0):

A 'seed' is something that provides a pseudonumber generator with its 'randomness'.  If you initialise it with the same seed, you will get the same 'random' pattern.

Here, you are probably passing the same seed in all the time.

Maybe you should define your function like this instead:

```
long double fn( long reps, default_random_engine & engine )
```

Declare a single instance of your random number generator when you run your program, and seed it *once* with a value that will always be different when your program starts (*eg* the system time).  Then, pass the generator into any functions that require random number generation.

Comment: So if i wanted to pass the seeds 1-10 through the generator, how would i go about doing so?

Comment: Have I possibly misunderstood your question?  It initially looked like you *didn't* want the same seed.  Are you saying that you get the same sequence no matter what seed you use?  Or do you just want to use 10 different seeds, but have them be different every time the program is run?

Comment: Sorry, may of been unclear.  I want to use 10 different seeds, specifically 1-10.

Comment: You said: *How can i get my x and y values to randomize and not be the same output every time the program executes?*.  The answer is to use a different seed every time.  If you force your program to use seeds 1-10 only (*eg* `seed = 1 + (time(0) % 10);`) then your program will only have 10 unique random sequences.